# Duplicate Key error when DELETING and INSERTING in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm running a mid-size system (PHP + MySQL) and I have a table stores all user's friends (this information comes from Facebook). The table now have about 1 million lines.

Every time user logs in, the system DELETEs all user`s friends from this table, and then insert it again using data downloaded from Facebook, so it's coded like this:

```
1) Run Facebook Query and store results in an object.

2) If query wasn`t successful, end program.

3) DELETE FROM UserFriends WHERE idUser = $idUser

4) INSERT INTO UserFriends (idUser, FriendFacebookId) VALUES
($idUser, $objFB[x]),
($idUser, $objFB[x2]),
($idUser, $objFB[x3])
...
```

* It generates the query inside a loop, so it INSERT all lines in one query only)

Sometimes (1 in ~2000) running the INSERT statement returns the following error:

```
1062 : Duplicate Entry for '2030-0202001910' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The `'2030-0202001910'` is the User's ID and the FriendFacebookID... it's always the first set of data in the INSERT statement.

So the question is: I've just deleted everything for this user, the table is supposed to be empty for this user, but then when I try to insert data for this user, it returns me this message. Why this happens and how can I avoid it?

Please note: This program runs hundreds times per hour, and the error occurs only few times... If the same user try to log in again, the program works like expected... So i'm thinking that can be some "delay" between the DELETE command and the data been removed from table... I don't know.

Useful information:Table is InnoDB and I'm not using transactions.

Comment: Have you checked that your input does not contain any duplicates in these cases? Anyway, it looks like a horrible way to update your database, I would compare the current set against the retrieved set and only store / delete the differences. Or get the differences directly from facebook if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I've compared and there's no duplicate data in the input set. I'm thinking in load data into a "temporary" table and then do the sync with the current data and the new data... But I think I'll spend more CPU, IO and Disk doing it instead of just erase everything and load again.

Comment: is it possible that another instance of the program does an insert with the same key between your delete and insert?

Comment: Perhaps a race condition when the user double-clicks the login button, causing 2 requests to be sent?

Comment: FuzzyTree and jeroen, It can be a answer... A user can eventually "double click" the login button and start two processes on the server... Maybe this is my problem... I'll check it. :-)

Comment: Just to confirm: The problem was the double-click on the submit button. I've created a script to disable the button once clicked, and now everything work just fine! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of insert: INSERT IGNORE

It is meant to mean 'ignore duplicates' so it never creates the possibility of creating a collision.

See if that works for you.

You could also use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

...or simply: REPLACE

instead of the plain INSERT command